# Failing to update ParseUser in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

FafApplication.sUserI can save a new `ParseUser`, but I can't update an existing user.

Note that `mUser` is set `onCreateView` via `mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`.

Here's my code:

```
public void updateProfile() {
    if (validateFields()) {
        // i know i should only save if the values are new, but I'd like to get this working first
        mUser.put("name", "new name");
        mUser.setEmail("new email");

        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profile.jpg", mPhotoData);
        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    mUser.put("profileImage", file);

                    mUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            // successful
                            if (e == null) {
                                ((EditProfileActivity) getActivity()).endActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.parse_profile_updated), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            // not successful
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "user " + getString(R.string.parse_try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "file " + getString(R.string.parse_try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following stack trace from Parse:

```
W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError
W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:352)
W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:258)
W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:188)
W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:184)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm not sure why I can't save the `ParseUser`. Why does the session need to change in order for me to save the `ParseUser`? How do I prevent this, or how do I update the `session` based on my `saveInBackground()` result?

Comment: Sounds like you need to call `logIn` before `save`

Comment: What do I do if it's a return user? Am I supposed to store a string of their username and password to call `logIn` again?

Edit - Turns out I can update the user. It only breaks when I'm logged in, installa new apk (due to testing without), then try to update the profile. Sounds like this will be an issue between versions in the app store, right?

Comment: Sounds like it.  Maybe you need to detect a version change and have the user log in again.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate. Does everyone have this issue, or do you think it's something I'm doing incorrectly (since you probably can't tell without looking through my code)?

Comment: I'm working on an app with parse login but I don't think I'm saving the user other than at sign in.  Based on your comment in the code, a lot of this could be mitigated by only saving if there's a change.  You might be able to combine that with `ParseUser.isAuthenticated` to see if you need to prompt for login and maybe it would be infrequent.

Comment: I may have to go the login prompt way. I know I should validate, I just haven't implemented it because I'd like to get the update working first. It doesn't matter if I change 1 or 100 fields, I still get the error.